# FileSystem in Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, html5-filesystem

How can I use FileSystem API in TypeScript in an Angular 4 application?

I added `@types/filesystem` to `devDependencies`, but I still get compile errors like

> Property 'resolveLocalFileSystemURL' does not exist on type 'Window'.
>
> Cannot find name 'FileError'.
>
> Cannot find name 'FileEntry'.

My `tsconfig.json` is almost the same as the one generated by angular-cli, I just added `"node_modules/typed-cordova-plugin-purchase` to `typeRoots`:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types",
            "node_modules/typed-cordova-plugin-purchase"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2016",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

Should I import anything?
Are there any examples of using FileSystem in Typescript?

Comment: Show us the code where you try to use it

Comment: See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#types-typeroots-and-types . Make sure you don't have `types` or you added it to `types` if you have them. Proper `typeRoots` never hurts. Please, provide tsconfig in the question.

Comment: @estus, I updated my question.

Comment: @FredrikLundin, even doing `window.requestFileSystem` throws the same kind of error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I made it finally work by adding `types` to `tsconfig.json`, actually `tsconfig.app.json` (I'm using angular CLI 1.0.1)

```
"types": [
    "cordova",
    "cordova-plugin-file"
]
```

Using `@types/filesystem` is not enough as `FileError` is not defined there, that's why I used `"@types/cordova-plugin-file`.

Comment: But why would one have to "borrow" the cordova type definitions? These should be defined somewhere as part of the standard DOM routines, right?

Comment: Apparently it seems like its not included in standard DOM. As I understand it, this api would still be experimental and it has been recommended not to implement types for it until it is more stable. You can see discussion here: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29548. Seems like the cordova-plugin-file could be a good alternative. I will try it out.

Answer (score 2):

As an addition to the previous answer, be sure to add @types/cordova (and possibly @types/cordova-plugin-file... see note below) to your project if you have not done so already.  That was my situation compiling an angular 5 based app to an alternate cordova-based target.

```
npm install @types/cordova --save
npm install @types/cordova-plugin-file --save
```

(the latter plugin states: This is a stub types definition for Apache Cordova File System plugin. Apache Cordova File System plugin provides its own type definitions, so you don't need @types/cordova-plugin-file installed!)